# Latitude saving as -90 With PostGIS RGeo Lat/Lng Points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, irb, rgeo, geographic-distance

I am working with Geo Spatial coordinates and was testing my coding in rails console

Looks like it is changing my longitude to -90.0 instead of what it should be -93.291557312011719

Any help would be appreciated..   tried it with just

"POINT(#{lng} #{lat})"

And

"POINT(#{lng.to_f} #{lat.to_f})"

Server info

```
CentOS 6.4
PostgreSQL 9.3
PostGIS 2.1  With Extensions of adminpack, fuzzystrmatch, pg_trgm, plpgsql
```

IRB console

```
1.9.3-p547 :001 > city = "springfield"                                                                                                                            
 => "springfield" 
1.9.3-p547 :002 > state = "mo"                                                                                                
 => "mo" 
1.9.3-p547 :003 > lng = "37.208969116210938"                                                                                                
 => "37.208969116210938" 
1.9.3-p547 :004 > lat = "-93.291557312011719"                                                                                                
 => "-93.291557312011719" 
1.9.3-p547 :005 > l = Location.new({:city => city, :state => state, :coords => "POINT(#{lng.to_f} #{lat.to_f})", :cs => "#{city}, #{state}"})
2014-07-25 08:31:02 DEBUG --    (18.5ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='locations'
 => #<Location id: nil, coords: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x56eb2f2 "POINT (37.20896911621094 -90.0)">, city: "springfield", state: "mo", zip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, cs: "springfield, mo", alt: nil>
```

But if I am not tring to save to DB I get this

```
l = "POINT(#{lng.to_f} #{lat.to_f})"                              
 => "POINT(37.20896911621094 -93.291557312011719)"
```

Here is my table for locations

```
 create_table "locations", :force => true do |t|
    t.spatial  "coords",     :limit => {:srid=>4326, :type=>"point", :geographic=>true}
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                                             :null => false
    t.string   "cs"
    t.text     "alt"
  end
```

Comment: Because in your example code you have assigned -93.29 to latitude, not longitude, which has been rounded down to -90, the lower possible bound for latitude?

Comment: Thanks i see that now... i assigned wrong variable... thanks if you post the answer i will accept it. Thanks for you help

Comment: There you go. Sometimes another pair eyes is all you need :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your example code you have assigned -93.29 to latitude, not longitude, which has been rounded down to -90, the lower possible bound for latitude. Presumably, RGeo is intelligent enough to round to the nearest acceptable value, rather than throwing an error.